# Insert value to the inherited fields django

Tags: django, django-views, django-users

I have custom user model like this

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,UserManager

class Test(User):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objects = UserManager()
```

I want to insert the data in inherited user model **'Test'** like this:

```
# views.py

def add_user(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
         try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            username = data['username']   //username,first_name,last_name are already present in the default user model. 

            title = data['title'] 
            first_name = data['fname']
            last_name = data['lname']
            Test.objects.create(username=username,title=title,
                                first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
         except:
     return JsonResponse({})
```

I'm trying to create a Test instance, **the problem** is When I send the request the data is not saved in the database and also I get no error message.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: i did not get any error.. but the values are not inserted.

Comment: Try to remove `try-except` block and look what it outputs

Answer (score 0):

Django request contains already an instance of the user who send the request:

```
# views.py

     def add_user(request):
         if request.method == 'POST':
             data = {
                 'username' : request.user.username,
                 'first_name' : request.user.first_name
                 'last_name' : request.user.last_name
                 'title' : request.data.get('title')
             }
            Test.objects.create(**data)
            return JsonResponse(data)
         return JsonResponse({})
```